# Is there HDFS Positional write similar to hdfsPread?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I wanted to store a file in HDFS through C just now, which includes positional write. Is there any possible way to do that.(I cannot use any column oriented Database like HBase for that)

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to store a file(such as text file) in HDFS and do a positional writes on that file later on in time?

Comment: @prashantsunkari yes, i wanted to update at a particular offset

Answer (score 0):

The output stream that HDFS uses, DFSOutputStream, has methods for writing to particular positions. In the following method it's the offset.

```
protected synchronized void writeChunk(byte[] b, int offset, int len, byte[] checksum)
```

The same holds true for DFSInputStreams, which have seek capability.

Comment: Thanx for the reply...Is there any C Function like this...similar to hdfsPread()

Comment: Sorry that is a bit out of my element. I only am familiar with the Hadoop and Java.  But if Hadoop has a c library, I'm sure there is some similar function